Update Spring Boot application.properties values during building in command line
I am trying to update an application.properties value while building a Spring Boot project with maven.
I have tried the following:
mvn clean package -Dspring.datasource.url="--jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]"

mvn clean package -Dspring.datasource.url='--jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]'

mvn clean package -Dspring.datasource.url="jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]"

mvn clean package -Dspring.datasource.url='jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]'

mvn clean package "-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]"

mvn clean package '-Dspring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]'

mvn clean package "-Dspring.datasource.url=--jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]"

mvn clean package '-Dspring.datasource.url=--jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password]'

In all of these instances, I'm getting the following error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver org.h2.Driver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, --jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=<masked>

But when I directly replace the spring.datasource.url value in my application.properties file, my project builds fine.
I am looking to do this without using Maven's filtering functionality; I know how to do that already and was under the impression that this was possible without filtering. Am I wrong in that assumption, or is there a way to do this?

I think this is an XY problem.  If you need that property to drive some tests, create a test profile, add this property to application-test.properties and activate the profile on your build with mvn package -Dspring.profiles.active=test

Or, you can try setting the environment variable on the build line: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password] mvn clean package

@lane.maxwell thanks. I tried export SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://[database-URL]/[database]?user=[username]&password=[password] && mvn clean package and the project built, but the DB source did not change.

Create a separate applicaton-test.properties files in your src/test/resources directory... and your test will run with it... They can directly select by your test @ActiveProfiles("test") or other things possible...
